# Redirect to page after dropdown selection for shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php

I've created a shopping cart with PHP and MySQL. It consists of two pages: `cart.php` (the actual cart) and `add_product.php` (the page that lets you add and remove products). `cart.php` generates a table row for every product (with `foreach($_COOKIE)` etc.), as can be seen in the screenshot below.

Let's imagine: the second product ("Cam") has product id 2. If I want to remove this product, I go to `add_product.php?product=6&amount=0` and it gets removed. I would like it if users were automatically redirected to this page immediately when they select 0 at "Aantal" (Dutch for "Amount"). And the same for all the other amounts: go to `add_product.php?product=6&amount=2` if the users selects 2 in the dropdown.

I know how you can do this for one dropdown, but how do I do this for multiple, automatically generated dropdowns? Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify your cart.php so it lets say add id of product to form's select with quantity:

```
<select data-product-id="<?=$productId;?>">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Using jquery you will have something like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){ 
    window.location = 'add_product.php?product=' +
        $(this).attr('data-product-id') + 
        '&amount= ' + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested this code, its like I just gave u basic idea of how it can be achieved. Have you tried to log errors or something?